# can't get data from provider to consumer

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have passed a stringified data which I received from my api endpoint to my child consumer and I want to iterate them through a material-ui table but I can't get them in my children but I get them in my parent component. Also the weird them that I can display the stringified data in my html page as they are!

App.js:

```
import axios from './axios-coins';
import CPContext from './context/context.js'


class App extends Component {

    state = {
      data: [],
      isLoading: true
    };

componentDidMount() {
      this.fetchData();
}

fetchData() {
  axios
    .get("")
    .then(response => {
      let res = response.data.data;


this.setState({data: res});
    })
    .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
}

render () {
    return (
      <CPContext.Provider 
        value={{
          data: this.state.data
        }}>
      </CPContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

children.js:

```
return (
                <CPContext.Consumer>
                  {context => (
                    <Paper className={classes.root}>
                    <Table className={classes.table}>
                      <TableHead>
                        <TableRow>
                          <CustomTableCell>id</CustomTableCell>
                          <CustomTableCell align="right">name</CustomTableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                      </TableHead>
                      <TableBody>
                      {Object.entries(context.data).map(v => (
                        <TableRow className={classes.row} >
                          <CustomTableCell component="th" scope="row">
                          {v[1].id}
                          </CustomTableCell>
                          <CustomTableCell align="right">{v[1].name}</CustomTableCell>

                         </TableRow>
                      ))}
                         </TableBody>
                    </Table>
                  </Paper> 
                  )}
            </CoinContext.Consumer>
        )
```

PS: in my app.js I can log these data as I'm logging them with object.entries method which I used in children.js.
Any help will be really appreciated!!

Comment: why do you want to pass data as an object's value instead of just passing it as an array?

Comment: Just earlier I wanted to make some tests and now I removed it, you can see updated code

Answer (score 0):

Use a wrapper for your text. For example, you must use this:

```
<p>{v[1].id}</p>
```

or:

```
<p>{v[1].name}</p>
```

Comment: I already tested this but I got an error: Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys

Comment: it is a normal material-ui table component